# pandas dataframe - index column header lower. Why?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want the index column header 'date' to be on the same row as all the other columns.  Right now, it's one row lower.  How can I fix this?

[image]

```
@app.route('/closeprice', methods=['POST']) #route tells Flask what URL should trigger the function
def closeprice():    
    tickersym = request.form['ticker']
    pandas_ds = get_historical_data(tickersym, start, end, output_format='pandas')
    pandas_ds['closechg']=pandas_ds.close.pct_change() #closing daily change 
    server_data = (pandas_ds.style.applymap(color_negative_red, subset=['closechg']).format({'closechg':"{:.2%}"})).render()
    return render_template('view.html',tickersym=tickersym,tables=[server_data],titles = tickersym)
```

Comment: Because date row is index. You may try reset_index method. Check documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
df.columns.name = df.index.name
df.index.name = None
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dates = pd.date_range('20130101', periods=6)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,4), index=dates, columns=["open","high","low","close"])

new_dates=df.index.set_names("date")
df.index=new_dates

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Save_Excel.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer,'page_1',float_format='%.5f')
writer.save()
```

I tried to copy the value of the date and assert a new column named 'date' into the table and then reset the index, and I got the same result.

[image]

You can get what you want by saving the table in a 'xlsx' form.